# Python function in node-red - Issue on Windows system

Tags: python, node-red

I have created a node[image]

[image]

In the Python function I have added simple code like:

```
return msg
```

But I am getting an error like:

```
s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\utf_32_le.py", line 11, in decode
    return codecs.utf_32_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-19: code point not in range(0x110000)`
```

The same workflow works on Linux system, but gives above error on Windows. system.
Can anyone suggest any solution related to this?

Comment: Edit the question to show exactly what you have in the function node.

Comment: The fucntion used here is node-red-contrib-python-function. @hardillb I have used a simple `return msg` which is in python.

Comment: What platform(s) are you running on? Both Node-RED and the browser?

Comment: I am running node-red in a browser.  Node with version 6.17.1

Comment: No, where and on what OS is the back end running and what browser and OS are you using to access it.

Comment: Okay. I am using windows system and google chrome accessing node-red. I need to know about the python environment. Like the function I have used here is node-red-contrib-python-function v0.0.5 .